# My Application crashes when assigning NSString to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

My app crashes when the control comes over here `[self loadNextList]`. I am not sure why this happeninging. Please let me know if you see the problem.

For the first time , it works i dont see any problem. and when the loadNextList method is called again it gets crashed.when crashing no error message found in the console.

```
NSString *myTierTwoID;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *myTierTwoID;

-(void)getData{

myTierTwoID = [myTierTwoDict objectForKey:myTierTwoTitle];

[self loadNextList];

}

-(void)loadNextList{
//==========================

  NSLog(@"%@ lloo",myTierTwoID);

  NSString *aTierTwoId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myTierTwoID intValue] + 1];

  NSLog(@"%@ aTierTwoId",aTierTwoId);

  myTierTwoID = aTierTwoId; // here it crashes the app

  NSLog(@"%@ lloo",myTierTwoID);
}
```

Comment: This question would be a lot more informative if you could add details like .... what kind of crash are you getting?  is there any additional information appearing in the console? I see `retain` in there... but just to make sure, are you using ARC or not?

Comment: nothing found in console for the crash

Comment: @user198725878 There must be some error message when the application crashes. Please post that message.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann : thanks for the reply. no information found for the crash in console.and what you mean by "ARC"

Comment: put the breakpoint at that line and try to fetch the value from the same.

Comment: If you're running this within Xcode, there's a debug output or console within Xcode you can get that crash info from.  If you're running this outside of Xcode (i.e. double click launched), then that info appears in Console.app.

Comment: Thank you all for the help indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property signature expects a retained value, so you should do this instead:

```
self.myTierTwoID = [myTierTwoDict objectForKey:myTierTwoTitle];
```

and

```
self.myTierTwoID = aTierTwoId;
```

Comment: one question do i need to use self when assigning value to the retained objects? and why? pls let me know

Comment: A synthesized property implementation is much more complicated than a simple assignment. The _retained_ qualifier involves releasing the old value object and retaining the new one. Without prepending "self." you skip the internal synthesized implementation (skipping release/retain too) and just assign a value. If you don't release the old value object, you leak memory. If you don't retain the new one, you are going to crash when it gets released elsewhere.